# Is it theoretically possible for an implementation to promote an unsigned int to an int?

Tags: c, standards, c99

According to the following two clauses from the C99 standard:

> **6.2.5-9**
>
> The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange
>   of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of
>   the same value in each type is the same.
>
> **6.2.6.2-2**
>
> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall
>   be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign
>   bit. There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one
>   sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as
>   the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding
>   unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in
>   the unsigned type, then M ≤ N ).

It is (probably) possible for a signed type to represent all numbers representable by the corresponding unsigned type. For example, if the `unsigned int` type is represented using 31 value bits and 1 padding bit and the signed int is represented using 31 value bits and no padding bits.

Is an implementation allowed to do so? If yes, does that mean that an `unsigned int` will be promoted to an `int` in such a case (since both types have the same conversion rank and `int` can represent all values that `unsigned int` represents)?

Comment: You cannot get a quart into a pint bottle - It is an idiom but true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is (probably) possible for a signed type to represent all numbers representable by the corresponding unsigned type. For example, if the unsigned int type is represented using 31 value bits and 1 padding bit and the signed int is represented using 31 value bits and no padding bits. Is an implementation allowed to do so?

The standard establishes in `6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions`:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>   If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

Since `int` and `unsigned int` are of the same rank (`6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers`), `int` will convert into `unsigned int`, but not the other way around:

> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>   signed integer type, if any.

Integer constants suffixed with `u` are always unsigned (see the table in `6.4.4.1 Integer constants`).

`6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers` clause 2 also tells us:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may
>   be used:
>
> — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
>   than the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer
>   promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So, no, an implementation cannot legally convert `unsigned int` into `int`, unless you ask for that explicitly by way of casting or assignment.

**EDIT**: Clause 2 of `6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers` reads as:

> — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is **less
>   than** the rank of int and unsigned int.

(INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ISO/IEC 9899 Second edition 1999-12-01)

> — An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is **less than or equal to** the rank of int and unsigned int.

(WG14/N1256 Committee Draft — Septermber 7, 2007 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3)

> — An object or expression with an integer type (**other than int or unsigned int**) whose integer conversion rank is **less than or equal to** the rank of int and unsigned int.

(N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010 ISO/IEC 9899:201x,
N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 ISO/IEC 9899:201x)

And just for fun, C++11's `4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom]`:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned
>   int.

(N3242=11-0012,
N3337 Date: 2012-01-16,
INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ISO/IEC 14882 Third edition 2011-09-01)

Comment: Won't the integer promotions go first? "the integer promotions are performed on both operands. **Then** the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:"

Comment: But those promotions apply to types smaller in rank than `int`, to all kinds of `short` and `char` and to bitfields. They do not apply to `unsigned int`. See `clause 2` of `6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers`.

Comment: The integer conversion rank doesn't have to be strictly smaller: "An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is **less than** or **equal** to the rank of int and unsigned int".

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze *But those promotions apply to types smaller in rank* actually the rank has to be less than or equal see 6.3.1.1p2.

Comment: @Alexandros - the wording makes it clear this refers only to different types.

Comment: @Alexandros See the update. You're reading a draft and not the official standard.

Comment: @ouah See the update. You're reading a draft and not the official standard.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I'm not reading a draft, I'm referring to the official ANSI copy of C11.

Comment: @ouah Could be. The question is about C99, though. See the tags and the text of the question.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze you should emphasize the *other than int or unsigned int* in 6.3.1.1p2. I think this is the answer to the question. The OP mentions C99 but my understanding is this amendment was done to avoid  this situation.

Comment: @ouah Ah, you're right. I, of course, have assumed that all time long as it's the only really meaningful interpretation (to me, at least). Damn, even the drafts differ!